# Stanford's AI course materials

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I've missed this course:( Googling doesn't help me find materials of this course.

Video lectures,labs e.t.c..

Is anybody here has a materials from this course?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all materials are available available in the internet: ai-class.com or if you prefer directly on youtube http://www.youtube.com/user/knowitvideos#g/u